# Can I point a subdomain directly to an API endpiont in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, cname, a-records

My rest API (node) is set up in AWS ECS behind a load balancer - `super-long-aws-lb-url`

I also have a domain registered and a subdomain for my backend which is set up as an A-record aliased to the load balancer; I access my rest API at something like `data.mydomain.com/api/resource/{:id}` - this is working as expected.

There's one endpoint that serves as a reverse proxy for accessing user-generated content - it's public and currently I can access it via
`data.mydomain.com/api/content/public/{:id}`

What I'd like to do is create a "pretty" url to just that endpoint in route53 so that the public endpoint becomes available via `content.mydomain.com/{:content-id}`

So far I've tried setting up this subdomain as a CNAME pointing directly to the string value composed of ALB URL + endpoint

`content.mydomain.com` -> `super-long-aws-lb-url/api/content/public/`

I expect that this will allow me to access that content at `http://content.mydomain.com/{:content-id}` but I get a Server Not Found error

Next I tried setting it up as an A-Record with an alias, but since it needs a resource with an IP address, I'm forced to select an AWS resource from a dropdown, and I'm back to using the load balancer without bypassing the global prefix (`api`) and the resource URL (`content/public`)

Is there a way to point a subdomain directly to an API endpoint in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Route 53 is a Domain Name Service (DNS).

DNS is used to resolve a domain name (eg `data.mydomain.com`) to an IP address, which allows traffic to be sent to a specific computer.

DNS *only* covers the domain name. It does not include anything after the slash.

Therefore, you can not use Amazon Route 53 to point to a 'path' (eg `/api/content/public/`).

Such redirection would be the job of any software running on the target computer. You can likely **configure this in your web server software**.